# Homing missile trouble with Math.atan2

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry, game-physics

I'm working on a homing missile for a horizontal-scrolling, space-shooter game in android.  I'm having trouble getting the desired behavior from the algorithm I'm using.  I would like for the missile to shoot out horizontally from the player's ship and then gradually home in on the target, with a chance to miss the target if the arc is too great.  It works, except if the missile misses the target, in which case, it generally attempts to follow the path of a sine wave, until it runs off the right side of the screen.  What I would like, is for the missile to attempt to keep circling around the target in its current curve (like the stereotypical homing missile) until it hits a sprite or runs off the edge of the screen.  I may add a limit so that it will explode and not keep spinning around on the screen, but that would be a later addition if I get this working.

Here's an example of the code:

```
public class HomingMissile extends Shot
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Rect sourceRect;
    Rect destRect;

    private double heading;

    private Sprite target;

    private int frameNumber;
    private int currentFrame;
    private int frameDelta;

    public HomingMissile(Context context, ImageLoader imageLoader, int x,
        int y, int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY, int dx, int dy)
    {
        super(context, imageLoader, x, y, minX, minY, maxX, maxY, dx, dy);

        heading = 0;

        frameNumber = 3;
        currentFrame = 0;
        frameDelta = 1;

        target = new Sprite(context, imageLoader, 300, 50, minX, minY, 
            maxX, maxY, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBitmap(int id)
    {
        bitmap = imageLoader.GetBitmap(id);

        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight() / frameNumber;

        sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, width - 1, height);
        destRect = new Rect(X, Y, X + width - 1, Y + height - 1);
    }

    public void setTarget(Sprite sprite)
    {
        target = sprite;
    }

    @Override
    public void Move()
    {
        if (!visible)
            return;

        final double f = 0.03;
        double oldHeading = heading;

        double atanY = target.Y + (target.height / 2) - Y;
        double atanX = target.Y + target.X - X;

        heading = (1 - f) * oldHeading + f * Math.atan2(atanY, atanX);

        X += Math.cos(heading) * 10;
        Y += Math.sin(heading) * 10;

        UpdateBounds();

        if (currentFrame == frameNumber - 1)
            frameDelta = -frameDelta;

        if (currentFrame < 0)
        {
            frameDelta = -frameDelta;
            currentFrame += frameDelta;
        }

        sourceRect.top = height * currentFrame;
        sourceRect.bottom = sourceRect.top + height;

        currentFrame += frameDelta;

        if (target.Collide(destRect, bitmap))
        {
            visible = false;

            heading = 0;
        }

        if (OutOfBounds())
        {
            visible = false;

            heading = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (visible)
        {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate((float) (heading * 180 / Math.PI) * 1.5f, X + width
                / 2, Y + height / 2);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, paint);
                canvas.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

The homing algorithm occurs in Move().  A partial solution I found to the problem was to add this check:

```
if (atanY >= 0 && atanX < 0)
    atanY = -atanY;
```

before the heading calculation, but the missile still bugs out if it is fired from a Y position greater than the target's Y position.

I've been battling with this for several days now, and I'm not very good with trig, so I'm hoping someone can help me.  I tried not to clutter up the question with code, but if anymore code or information is needed, I can provide it.

Thanks!

### EDIT

I changed the line:

```
double atanX = target.Y + target.X - X;
```

to:

```
double atanX = target.X - X;
```

but, if the missile is fired from a Y position greater than the target's Y position, it still bugs out.  It dives toward the target, but if it misses, it abruptly curves up as if it were going to do a loop-de-loop.

Comment: I can't say my trigonometry is all up there, but i believe atan is used to find the angle between the x-axis and and a x,y vector.
Looking at it like that your definition of the atanX in your Move function seems rather weird. Shouldn't that be atanX = target.X+(target.width/2) - X

Comment: I always find that the simplest and most efficient way to solve these kinds of problems is to sit down with an old-fashioned pencil and a sheet of paper and draw the scenario.

Comment: Instead of using a heading you could try with vectors:
    `double magnitude = sqrt(atanX*atanX + atanY*atanY);
    X += atanX/magnitude*10;
    Y += atanY/magnitude*10;`

Comment: Right, with vectors this would be much easier.  Then the heading you want the missile to move in would just be `playerPosition - missilePosition`; and to figure out which way to rotate you can just take the cross-product

Comment: The point of me using the heading was so that the missile could gently turn into an alignment with the target, so it would simulate how a rocket making a sharp turn would look.  With the vector way, the missile heads straight towards the target and does not arc the way I'd like it to.  Maybe there is a way to achieve this with the vector solution?

Comment: @Pirokiko When you asked about atanX = target.X+(target.width/2) - X, if you were coming to that conclusion based on what I had for atanY, then I should tell you that the only reason I had a different equation for atanY was that I was trying to aim the missile towards the front of the ship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably due to crossing the 360 degrees / 0 degrees boundary.

Using h = heading i.e. the direction the missile is travelling in, and t = the direction from the missile to the target and f=0.1. Now consider the situation where t is 20 degrees clockwise to h.

If h = 180 then t = 200 and h(final) = 0.9*180+0.1*200 = 182, so the missile has turned a small amount clockwise as expected.

But if h = 350 then t = 370 = 10 (according to the atan formula), so now h(final) = 0.9*350+0.1*10=316 and the missile has turned a large distance in the wrong direction.

You need to add a little logic to check for the zero crossing and avoid this problem.

**Added comment**

OK - atan is always a tricky thing, as b = tan(a) is valid for any a in the range (-inf < a < + inf), but a = atan(b) will always provide a b in some range (bmin <= b < bmin + 360), so as a vector rotates around in a circle, at some point there will be a discontinuity in the calculated angle as it rises past bmin + 360 and immediately drops to bmin or as it falls below bmin and suddenly jumps up to bmin + 360. If I am not making myself clear, then just consider what happens when a clock goes past 12:59 pm. It doesn't continue on to 13:00 (except in Europe), but instead drops back to 1:00 am.

Blackbear's answer shows the correct idea. My equivalent 'fix' would be to replace your line

```
  heading = (1 - f) * oldHeading + f * Math.atan2(atanY, atanX);
```

with something like

```
  TheAngle = Math.atan2(atanY, atanX);
  if Abs(TheAngle-oldheading) > 180 then
    TheAngle = TheAngle - Sign(TheAngle)*360;
  heading = (1 - f) * oldHeading + f * TheAngle;
```

where Sign(x) = +1 for x >=0 and -1 for x < 0

Note that my code is not quite in C++, Java, or whatever you are using, so you won't be able to do a direct cut-and-paste - but you should be able to translate it into something useful.

Comment: You seem to be really familiar with the theory of all this.  I tried what BlackBear suggested and it didn't work.  I think you guys are suggesting the same solution, so could you check out the comment I left oh his post?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem a while ago, the solution was pretty trivial once found out actually ;) This is the offending code of my update routine, it's part of an helper class so you can consider owner to be your missile and target its target. It's python but should be straightforward:

```
vectorToTarget = target.position - owner.position
ang = vectorToTarget.angle() - owner.angle

self.distanceToTarget = vectorToTarget.length()

if ang < -180:       # \
    ang += 360       #  | 
                     #  |-- this solved the problem!
elif ang > 180:      #  |
    ang -= 360       # /

self.angleToTarget = ang
owner.movement.turn(ang)
```

ang is the angle the owner should turn in order to face its target. The solution was to add the marked part to correct that behavior

Comment: I separated my atan2 calculation from my bearing calculation and looked at its value after each iteration of my Move() method.  I discovered that the result of atan2 always approaches 180 (or -180, depending on if you're firing from above or below the target), and then the sign inverts.  So, it will get to say 178 and then the next pass, its value will be -176.  This seems like what you're talking about, but I tried your fix and it didn't help.  Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: See my added comment below, in my answer